# NHibernate: Could not create the driver from Test.SqlServerCeDriver_ImageFix

Tags: nhibernate, sql-server-ce

Im trying to resolve an issue where when using NHibernate with a SqlServerCeDriver that uses an image column you receive an error: "Byte array truncation to a length of 8000.". I found the following solution:

http://mgeorge-notes.blogspot.com/2009/05/nhibernate-mapping-from-binary-to.html

And created the following class:

```
namespace Test
{
    public class SqlServerCeDriver_ImageFix : SqlServerCeDriver
    {
        protected override void InitializeParameter(IDbDataParameter dbParam, string name, SqlType sqlType)
        {
            base.InitializeParameter(dbParam, name, sqlType);

            if (sqlType is BinarySqlType)
            {

                PropertyInfo dbParamSqlDbTypeProperty = dbParam.GetType().GetProperty("SqlDbType");

                dbParamSqlDbTypeProperty.SetValue(dbParam, SqlDbType.Image, null);

            }

        }

    }
}
```

But when I change the NHibernate mapping from
    NHibernate.Driver.SqlServerCeDriver
to
    Test.SqlServerCeDriver_ImageFix
I get the error, but I am not sure why.

The inner exception is: "Could not load type Test.SqlServerCeDriver. Possible cause: no assembly name specified."

Anyone have any ideas as to what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining the driver in the config, define it with the [AssemblyQualifiedName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx), i.e.:

```
Test.SqlServerCeDriver_ImageFix, MyAssemblyThatContainsThisType
```